# Errors when installing jdk 1.7 in linux

Tags: java, linux, oracle, installation, java-7

When I am installing jdk 1.7 in Oracle Linux by using the following

rpm -ivh jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm

However I am getting the following errors, how can I resolve these errors and install jdk 1.7?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

```
rpm -ivh /tmp/mnt/jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/charsets.pack
        tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/lib/tools.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/deploy.pack
```

My Linux version is  `oracle linux 5.5`

Comment: This is not a programming question.  In fact, it *looks* like a basic system administration question ... on how to install Java on a Linux machine.

Comment: @StephenC So where to move this question?

Comment: superuser.com or serverfault.com, depending on whether you are doing this in a "professional capacity".  (It is a somewhat bizarre distinction, IMO ... but that is the way that they play it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I agree with Stephen C - this definitely sounds like "permissions"

2) "sudo" - you must definitely run the command as "root"

3) Do an `ls -ld /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/` to make sure the directory exists.

If it doesn't, consider doing a "mkdir /usr/java" and re-running the command

4) This thread will probably be migrated to "superuser.com", which is more for administrative questions

5) If you still don't have a solution, please be sure to specify your Linux version.

==================================================================================

ADDENDUM:

The post gave the impression the JDK install failed; it sounded like *none* of the RPM was getting extracted.

Based on the subsequent information, it sounds like it's merely a warning:

> - http://www.geilthings.com/wiki/Java#1.7.x
>
> In version 7u9, shows the following error messages related to file
>   extension pack, which is used in the facilities of Java applications,
>   using Java Web Start. This does not affect the functionality of the
>   JRE installed on your system, made ​​by this binary package format
>   (RPM).
>
> - http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=285076
>
> Your install of Sun jdk-7u7-linux-x64.rpm was successful. The error
>   messages displayed, are normal. They exist because those files don't
>   exist in the package. I get them when installing the Sun jre rpm
>   packages. Just ignore those particular error messages.

Comment: I ran as root and directory /usr/java does exists.

Comment: So did you look to see if "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/" existed, too????  If not, did you try a "mkdir /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09" to see if you had permission to create it???  This is all basic troubleshooting...  PS: Exactly what *is* your Linux version?

Comment: My linux version is oracle linux 5.5. Thanks

Comment: usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09 was created when I installed the jdk

Comment: Please read my addendum above

Comment: After installation if try java -version, I am getting `java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)`

Comment: After installation I did a reboot and that solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I started getting these .pack errors after I aborted an rpm installation and it ended up in a weird unfinished state that even --force couldn't sort out. java wouldn't run because of "java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object" What ended up working for me was a full uninstall using instructions on this page http://blog.csdn.net/cnweike/article/details/17005825. Specifically, I was trying to uninstall using `rpm -e` RPM_FILE_NAME as opposed to the correct installed name that `rpm -qa` returns.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to tun the `rpm` command as root.

Another possibility is that SELinux is getting in the way.  Do you have SELinux enforcing enabled with the strict policy?

Comment: Hi Stephen rpm has been run as root