# RHEL : JDK 7u15 installation error

Tags: java, java-7, rpm, rhel, rhel6

I am getting following error while installing the JDK 7u15 version on Red Hat Enterprise Linux box.

I am not able figure out what to do with it? I mean what is impact on running my programs?

What are these pack files?

```
charsets.pack
deploy.pack
javaws.pack
jsse.pack
localedata.pack
plugin.pack
rt.pack
```

I have followed the steps given in oracle site:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html

RHEL version: 6

Here is the exact message from putty:

```
bash-4.1$ sudo rpm -ivh jdk-7u15-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]

    Unpacking JAR files...
     rt.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/rt.pack
     jsse.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/jsse.pack
     charsets.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/charsets.pack
     tools.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/lib/tools.pack
     localedata.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
     plugin.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/plugin.pack
     javaws.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/javaws.pack
     deploy.jar...
    Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/lib/deploy.pack
```

Comment: It's been answered, but for future reference, another `v` in the command line would show you every command it was attempting to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I have got the same problem on Fedora. After researching on the Internet, it has been discussed somewhere (I will add the reference later if I can find it again) that these are normal. It appears that the installer is trying the open *.pack file when they are already gone because they are renamed to *.jar. For some reasons, they are not trying to fix this problem in any newer installer.

Here are the references:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=283237

http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/Howto_install_proprietary_Java_from_Oracle

[Errors when installing jdk 1.7 in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302271/errors-when-installing-jdk-1-7-in-linux)

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=285076

Comment: Thanks this will helps me a lot.